# Fullscreen of '_blank' properties window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open, intel-xdk

I'm doing an app using Intel XDK.

On iphone, after you open a window using this script:

```
window.open('http://intel.com', '_blank', '');
```

How can i go back to the app without closing the app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin in project settings, then it will have bottom bar with 'Done' button to go back. If you have not included the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin then it will just open full screen like you are experiencing.